# Unable to get a single large size for Facebook Graph API user's photos edge

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, swift4

I am using the facebook sdk for login and user_photos purpose in a iOS Application.

The login is done and in the permissions I added the `user_photos` `readPermissions`.

But when I am trying to fetch the user photos using the graphPath: me/photos with `fields` parameters- `id,picture`, only the smallest of the images size is returned. I have tried using `picture.type(large)` or `picture.width(640)` , but nothing works.

I tried using the `images` parameter for `fields`, it returns all the sizes for the Photo node.

I even tried using the edge `<OBJECT_ID>/picture` with `fields` parameter `picture`, but it gives a `facebook sdk error(error code 6)`.

How to get the user photos with just a single photo link to a large size ?

I am using the latest version of the SDK.

Comment: _“I tried using the images parameter for fields, it returns all the sizes for the Photo node.”_ - so, go pick the one you like out of that then …?

Comment: I was hoping that the graph API do return itself a single larges size using some field, which I might not know of. If this is not the case, then I would need to find out for every Photo node, which one is the largest.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift - try this**

```
@IBAction func facebookLoginButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
            let fbLoginManager: FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
            fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email", "pages_show_list"], from: self) { (result, error) in
                if (error == nil){
                    let fbLoginResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
                    if fbLoginResult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                        if(fbLoginResult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")){
                            self.facebookLogin()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
    func facebookLogin() {
        if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil) {
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email "]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
                if result == nil {
                }
                else{
                    self.userResults = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    self.email = (self.userResults["email"] as? String) ?? ""
                    if (self.email != "") {
                        let url = URL(string: "http://graph.facebook.com/\(YOURE FACEBOOK ID)/picture?type=large")!
                        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                        let downloadPicTask = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                            // The download has finished.
                            if let e = error {
                                print("Error downloading cat picture: \(e)")
                            } else {
                                if let res = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                                    print("Downloaded cat picture with response code \(res.statusCode)")
                                    if let imageData = data {
                                        let image: UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                                    } else {
                                        print("Couldn't get image: Image is nil")
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    print("Couldn't get response code for some reason")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        downloadPicTask.resume()
                    }
                    else{
                        Utility.showAlert("Login Faild", message: error?.localizedDescription, viewController: self)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will be giving the profile picture. What I have asked in the question is about user **photos**, not just profile picture.