# Facebook Graph API Issues

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, fbsdkloginkit

i am implementing facebook graph APi for get posts list but i am getting error in this Here Is my Code

```
var Requset : FBSDKGraphRequest

        print("\(FBSDKAccessToken.current())")

        let acessToken = String(format:"%@", FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString) as String

        print("\(acessToken)")

        let parameters1 = ["access_token":FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString]


        Requset  = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me/?fields=feed{message,full_picture,id,application,likes{name,pic_crop},comments{message,from,created_time},created_time}", parameters:parameters1, httpMethod:"GET")

        Requset.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            //MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(appDelegate.window, animated: true)

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                print("fetched user: \(result)")

                //var dataDict: AnyObject = (result! as AnyObject).object(forKey: "data")!

            }
```

i am getting error in this error is given below

> Error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x60000005fbf0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=(null)?

can any one tell me how to solve this

Comment: test with a lower amount of fields, with the graph api explorer

Comment: Yes Sure i am checking it if any issue then i will tell you thanks

Comment: Still i am not able to get response and i am testing with same fields in graph api explorer then its working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50559755/5146460

Comment: not this type bro i want facebook post list which was posted by perticular app